# External JavaScript not running even thought path is correct

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run my script, but HTML is having some trouble getting it. I have followed w3s tutorials but I can't seem to find the problem here.

```
<!doctype html>   
<html lang="en">      
<head> 

  <title>Javascript</title>    
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta name="" content="HTML5">      
  <script type="text/javascript" src="h5.js"></script>  

</head>       
<body> 

    <p> Book details: <div id="bookDetails"> </div> </p>

</body> 
</html>
```

h5.js

```
 window.onload = callFunctions; 

    function callFunctions() { 

        var book = {
            name: "Javascript",
            authors: ["Carl Coder","Peter Programmer"],
            isbn: "ABC-12345-XY",   
            bookDetails: function(){return "name:" + this.name + "authors:" + this.authors + "isbn: " + this.isbn;}
        };
        document.getElementById("bookDetails").innerHTML = book.bookDetails();
    }
```

Comment: You may need to give more detail. Where is your js file in regards to your html file?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code as it works in a snippet. It must be a file path/permissions/security issue in your local env.

Comment: Both are inside a folder located in desktop.